# force call to QString(const char *) constructor in Qt 4.7

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to compile a library written in Qt 4.6. On my current Linux machine I have only Qt 4.7 installed. The following code part:

```
/*file try.h*/
void fileOpen(QString s = NULL) ; 

/*file try.cpp*/
void MainWindow::fileOpen(QString s) {
     QString filename ;
     if(s.isNull()) filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
    this,
    "Choose a file",
    ".",
    "Source file (*.)");
else filename = s ;
}
```

compiles with the following error (I used cmake but the corresponding line code is the one listed above):

```
In member function ‘virtual int MainWindow::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int,     
void**)’:                                                                                          
/homes/combi/hodorog/Developments/axelOld/build/axel/src/QGui/moc_MainWindow.cxx:141:26:        
error: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘QString’ is ambiguous
/homes/combi/hodorog/Developments/axelOld/build/axel/src/QGui/moc_MainWindow.cxx:141:26:   
note: candidates are:
/usr/include/QtCore/qstring.h:426:43: note: QString::QString(const char*)
/usr/include/QtCore/qstring.h:105:14: note: QString::QString(const QChar*)
```

So I am guessing the problem is that in qt. 4.7. there are two QString constructors that can take a pointer as an argument (as listed in the compilation error), whereas in qt 4.6. there is only one QString constructor that can take a pointer as an argument. How can I force QString to call the constructor with const char * as an argument?

Thank a lot for your help in advance,
madalina

Answer (score 2):

`void fileOpen(QString s = NULL);`

You are trying to construct a `QString` object with `0`. It seems you are confusing the null of pointers with a null `QString`. A null `QString` is one which is created with the constructor `QString()`. Given how your function is implemented (referring to `s.isNull()`), you should change the function declaration to

```
void fileOpen(QString s = QString());
```

Comment: yes indeed, that was the problem. Is working now, thanks a lot.